# SQL Job Agent DB Restore fails with error #6107: Only user processes can be killed

Tags: sql-server, database-restore, single-user

We have an SQL Job Agent that runs in the "wee hours" to restore our local database (FooData) from a production backup.

First, the database is set to SINGLE_USER mode and any open processes are killed. Second, the database is restored.

But the 3rd step fails occasionally with Error 6107: "Only User Processes Can Be Killed"

This happens about once or twice a week at seemingly random intervals.  Here is the code for step 3 where the failure occasionally occurs:

```
USE master;
go
exec msdb.dbo.KillSpids FooData;
go
ALTER DATABASE FooData SET MULTI_USER;
go
```

Does anybody have any ideas what might be occurring to cause this error? I'm thinking there might be some automated process starting up during step 3 or possibly some user trying to log in during that time?  I'm not a DBA, so I'm guessing at this point, although I believe that a user should not be able to log in while the DB is in SINGLE_USER mode.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kill only user processes in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45843709/kill-only-user-processes-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem by changing one line of code which worked like a charm.

As mentioned in the original question, the 'KillSpids" line is used in Step 1 of the job. (Along with SET SINGLE USER) The 'KillSpids' made sense in Step 1 because there may be unwanted processes still active on the database.

The 'KillSpids' line was then added again into Step 3, but it was unnecessary, and was also causing the 6107 error.

I replaced the 'KillSpids' line with the one shown below. Setting the freshly restored database to single user mode takes care of the concern that a user might try to log in before all the job steps have been completed.  Here is the updated code:

```
USE master;
go
ALTER DATABASE [FooData] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
go
ALTER DATABASE FooData SET MULTI_USER;
go
```

Answer (score 6):

A user probably isn't logged in.  The system is probably performing some task.  The output of `exec sp_who` or `sp_who2` will show what sessions are open.  Any SPID below 50 is a system process, and cannot be killed with `KILL`.  The only way to stop them is to stop the SQL Server service or issue a `SHUTDOWN` command (which does the same thing).