# Kill only user processes in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

We have users that forget to close their access queries that use our SQL 2014 databases. When this happens it prevents the tables they are accessing from being rebuilt over night.  Is there any way to Kill these users and not kill the system processes.  From what I've read system processes are not only limited to SPID >50.

Answer (score 4):

Killing user processes based on `spid>=50` seems to be not reliable.

From Adam Machanic:[Smashing a DMV Myth: session_id > 50 == User Process](http://dataeducation.com/smashing-a-dmv-myth-session_id-50-user-process/)

> A recent conversation on an MVP mailing list revealed that this magic number, while perhaps once a legitimate filter, is certainly not safe to use in SQL Server 2005 or SQL Server 2008. Several system features can--and will--use session IDs greater than 50, because there is simply not enough room otherwise.

Examples include:

- Large servers that use soft NUMA, because there is one checkpoint and lazy writer thread per NUMA node
- Asynchronous statistics updating, again (and especially) on larger servers
  Database mirroring, especially if a large number of databases are involved
- Service Broker activation, when a large number of activation tasks are being used

And there may be other cases as well. **The point is, the number 50 is no longer a valid way to filter out system session IDs.**

so your options are

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions
WHERE
    is_user_process = 1

SELECT *
FROM sys.sysprocesses
WHERE
    hostprocess > ''
```

You can use above queries to get spids/session other than system and use kill command to kill them

Answer (score 0):

I think a combination of using sp_who and KILL should be possible, looking at Login name, hostname, etc. from sp_who

Comment: That's already available in the Activity Monitor and completely impractical for maintenance tasks.

Comment: In what way is it impractical?

Comment: Are *you* going to get up at 1 am, go back to the office and start closing connections one by one, every day ?

Comment: No, I'm going to write a stored procedure. I think I found something that will work. I've tested it and so far.

Comment: Exactly, create a stored procedure that runs prior to maintenance, iterating results from sp_who and running Kill on orphaned sessions. MSFT has always advocated using SP's or system views instead of system tables as they can change.

Answer (score 0):

> We have users that forget to close their access queries that use our
>   SQL 2014 databases. When this happens it prevents the tables they are
>   accessing from being rebuilt over night.

You can put your database in `single user` mode (with rollback immediate) and then in `multi user` before you start your maintenance. All user transactions will be rolled back.

Comment: Yes, of course, we has this as the first job step in the night maintenance, but you can wrap it into stored procedure, why not

Answer (score -1):

This stored procedure works and kills hanging access queries and doesn't kill system processes.

```
DECLARE @v_spid INT
DECLARE c_Users CURSOR
FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT SPID
FROM master..sysprocesses (NOLOCK)
WHERE spid>50 
AND status='sleeping' 
AND DATEDIFF(mi,last_batch,GETDATE())>=60
AND spid<>@@spid


OPEN c_Users
FETCH NEXT FROM c_Users INTO @v_spid
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS=0)
BEGIN
PRINT 'KILLing '+CONVERT(VARCHAR,@v_spid)+'...'
EXEC('KILL '+@v_spid)
FETCH NEXT FROM c_Users INTO @v_spid
END

CLOSE c_Users
DEALLOCATE c_Users
```

Comment: The OP specifically states that spid > 50 is not reliable. This answer does not address that.